# Which type of field I can add in wordpress like custom field that will have the opportunity to add multiple values

Tags: wordpress, field, taxonomy

I had Taxonomy category that must had such opportunity to add multiple fields from admin panel and get them like the picture[image: question].So for example what i can create that will give the user opportunity to add the fields dynamically and how can I get their values?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and used plugin [Custom Field Suite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-field-suite/)
It has a field type ***Loop*** and it was what I needed to add how many how needed.